# Silverlight Application with WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I have use the following code snippet to fetch the data from WCF service by using the following code snippet.

```
 EmployeeServiceClient serviceClient=new EmployeeServiceClient();
            serviceClient.GetDataCompleted += new EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs>(serviceClient_GetDataCompleted);
            serviceClient.GetDataAsync(5);
```

But I got the following exception on that how to resolve this problem .

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  Message=The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
Parameter name: via
  StackTrace:
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelFactory`1.ValidateScheme(Uri via)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.ValidateCreateChannelParameters(EndpointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.OnCreateChannel(EndpointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelFactoryBase`1.InternalCreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelFactoryBase`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.ServiceChannelFactoryOverRequest.CreateInnerChannelBinder(EndpointAddress to, Uri via)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.CreateServiceChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1..ctor(ClientBase`1 client)
       at GridDataControlSilverlightWCFService.ServiceReference1.EmployeeServiceClient.EmployeeServiceClientChannel..ctor(ClientBase`1 client)
  InnerException:
```

My exact requirement load the data from service to  Silverlight main project.
Can you please help any one on this .Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Rajasekar

Comment: can you post the configuration of the wcf client?

Comment: Might need to use <httpsTransport> instead of <httpTransport>